# Rails Devise token generator with service objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am working on a fairly large Rails app which due to large no of activities uses service objects (& light-services gem). Typically actions are performed in steps in the services, with many of the functions/objects used in these steps instantiated in the model it is working with (Customer.rb) in this case.

In one step I am trying to generate a Devise reset_password_token, but hit a glitch

```
Customer.rb

  def self.generate_token
    Devise.token_generator
  end
```

and then in service object reset_password.rb

```
  def generate_token
    raw, hashed = Devise.token_generator.generate(Customer, :reset_password_token)
    producer.reset_password_token = hashed
    producer.reset_password_token_sent_at = Time.now.utc
    @token = raw
  end
```

All that goes in to db is the timestamp, and a nil, nil for token although token gets put in to the url endpoint so is being generated

If anyone encountered this scenario before, tips more than welcome!

Here is rest of code, not setting the token in DB properly.

def validate_producer_email
self.valid_email = EmailValidator.valid?(producer.email)
end

```
  # @return [TrueClass, FalseClass]
  def validate_token
    self.producer.reset_password_token = reset_password_token, params['reset_password_token']
    customer = Customer.producer.find_by(reset_password_token: reset_password_token)
    # true if customer.email && Devise.secure_compare(reset_password_token, params[:reset_password_token])
    customer.present?
  end

  def update_producer
    return if ask_underwriter?

    Producer::Update
      .with(self)
      .run(
        producer: producer,
        force: current_administrator.blank?,
        params: {
          customer: {
            reset_password_token: reset_password_token
          }
        }
      )
  end
```

If anyone has any tips on how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error, again? Would be nice to see some stacktrace too.

Comment: Hi is no error, but in db is placed, nil, nil, and the timestamp, so it is not generating token (and check_token is not catching that, but that is another issue, first want the token!)

Comment: Update, am getting token is generated and gets in to the url raw but that and the hashed one are not getting put in to database, show as nil, nil